# Unity: login into facebook with Soomla and Facebook SDK is always opens at browser

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, facebook-unity-sdk, soomla

Soomla core version: 1.3.1
Facebook SDK version:  7.2.2
Unity: 5.3.3

Trying to login into facebook from unity game (by using SoomlaProfile.Login(Provider.FACEBOOK);)

The problem is: it always opens the login screen into the Safari, not in the Facebook app.

Setting the shareDialogMode = ShareDialogMode.NATIVE; inside the MobileFacebook.cs doesn't help. It was AUTOMATIC by-default but it opens browser, not the app. Facebook app is installed.

How could i fix it? I need to open Facebook app if it installed and run login inside it.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand from the Facebook developers site, according to this bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/ , the Facebook iOS sdk 4.6 does this **by design**.
You are using the Facebook SDK version: 7.2.2, which has the underlying iOS 4.7 sdk. (according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log, v7.2.0 - October 13, 2015 was updated to iOS sdk 4.7) 
It seems that for iOS9 and Facebook SDK > 7.2.0 this is an intended behavior due to the changes in iOS9 (read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9).
I hope this helped, and I did not misinterpret the problem or the versions.